# Why does spring's getLocalHost throw an exception on my server?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-el

I can build and run this application locally on my Windows machine using Tomcat 7 and Java 7.

But when I deploy the war file on a linux machine using Tomcat 7 and Java 7, an exception is thrown.  The problem seems to be in the SPeL function getLocalHost()

This is a snippet from my jms-context.xml file :

```
  <jms:listener-container
        connection-factory="AQjmsFactory"
        container-type="default"
        destination-type="durableTopic"
        client-id="THERMO-PERSON-FILTER"
        acknowledge="transacted"
        concurrency="8-16">
    <jms:listener destination="TRAIN_INFO_QUEUE" ref="personEventGateway" subscription='THERMOEVENT#{ T(java.net.InetAddress).getLocalHost().getHostName().replaceAll(".mycompany.com","").replaceAll("\.","").replaceAll("-","") }'/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

And when I deploy the war file, the error looks like this :

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[2013-12-11 16:22:43,499] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bb334a: defining beans [THERMOSerializer,erpuserService,erpuserDao,txManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,log4jInitialization,personJmsTemplate,erpJmsTemplate,personEventGateway,erpEventGateway,personFilterObj,erpBusObj,AQjmsFactory,org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0,org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#1,jmsFactoryDelegate,jmsFactory,THERMOInfoQueue,THERMOUpdatesQueue,aqDataSource,bizDataSource]; root of factory hierarchy
[2013-12-11 16:22:43,500] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getLocalHost' on object of type 'java.lang.Class'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:548)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1447)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getLocalHost' on object of type 'java.lang.Class'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ExpressionInvocationTargetException: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'getLocalHost' on object of type 'java.lang.Class'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwSimpleExceptionIfPossible(MethodReference.java:162)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:145)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:39)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: TRAIN-test1: TRAIN-test1: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:140)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: TRAIN-test1: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    ... 77 more
Dec 11, 2013 4:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 11, 2013 4:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/THERMO-event-processor] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 11, 2013 4:22:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/THERMO-event-processor] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: Have you specified `TRAIN-test1` as a host anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the root cause of the exception...

`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: TRAIN-test1`

This means a problem with the network configuration of the linux box; could be lots of things - like an incorrect `/etc/hosts` file, problems with `/etc/resolv.conf`, etc, etc ...

Comment: Thanks for replying Gary.  I am sure that the linux server's hostname is TRAIN-test1 ( by running >hostname ).  But I think you are correct.  If I try to > ping TRAIN-test1 , I get "Unknown host" .  If I use the fully qualified domain TRAIN-test1.mycompany.com, it works.